# check if URL contains some text (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i use javascript/jQuery to check if a URL contains a specific link/text.

for example :
A user browse to my site and his URL is : "http//www.mywebsite.com/userprofile/abc&from=home"
I have set a variable and its value is "http//www.mywebsite.com/userprofile/abc" , i want to know how to detect **if** "http//www.mywebsite.com/userprofile/abc" **exist in the URL**("http//www.mywebsite.com/userprofile/abc&from=home") then execute a function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var urlToCheck = "http//www.mywebsite.com/userprofile/abc";

if (window.location.href.indexOf(urlToCheck) > -1) {
  executeAFunction();
}
```